# Grouping and reordering boxplots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I need to group boxplots (subgroups) and reorder them (groups) according to a group that subgroups belong to.

R scripts that I used are:

```
data<-read.delim("clipboard")

p <- ggplot(data, aes(Class2,cM))

p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(Class1))) +
     geom_jitter(alpha = 0.4, position = position_jitter(height = .01, width = .35)) +
     coord_flip()
```

and I generated this (Class1=group; Class2=subgroup).

[image: grouping boxplots]

Please download a data table from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcq8aa0cv46udam/test-linkage.xlsx).

As you can see, groups are not organised in the graph. I would appreciate it if you could help me with this. Since some subgroups do not have more than one value, we can't see colours to indicate what group they belong to. It would be great if you could add labels to show which subgroups are in which group.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably better moved to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide data in a text format, not xls.

Solution 1: convert Class2 to a factor and set the levels in the required order

```
data$Class2 <- factor(
    data$Class2, 
    levels = c("group1:b", "group1:c", "group2:a")
)
```

Solution 2: use a facet_wrap instead of a fill

```
ggplot(data, aes(x= Class2, y = cM)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.4, position = position_jitter(height = .01, width = .35)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~Class1)
ggplot(data, aes(x= Class2, y = cM)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.4, position = position_jitter(height = .01, width = .35)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~Class1, scales = "free_x")
```